# Cross Object Formula Field

Tags: formula, formula-field, standard-objects

i need to update a picklist value (in Contact object) when in account object is selected another value.I know that this is possible with workflow but my 
customer has  a professional edition. Can i do that with cross object formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never update a field using a formula. You are referring to using a formula **instead** of the picklist.

Yes, that works, just create a formula on Contact and get the `Account.yourfield`.